# Rails 4: after_update callback leads to endless loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I use the after_update callback in my User model.

**Model User.rb**

```
after_update :check_phone

check_phone
  phone_validation if phone_changed?
end

def phone_validation
  code = Array.new(8){rand(36).to_s(36)}.join
  self.phone_verification_code = code
  self.save
end
```

However, this leads to an endless loop. The problem is that the callback is called again after `self.save` in the phone_validation method. `phone_changed?` apparently still returns `true`. How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

**User.rb**

```
attr_accessor  :phone_checked

after_update :check_phone, :unless => "phone_checked"

check_phone
  phone_validation if phone_changed?
end

def phone_validation
  code = Array.new(8){rand(36).to_s(36)}.join
  self.phone_verification_code = code
  self.phone_checked = true  # update flag
  self.save
end
```

**OR**

*use with caution:* [skip callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks)

```
def phone_validation
 code = Array.new(8){rand(36).to_s(36)}.join
 self.update_column(:phone_verification_code => code)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case `self.save` triggers the [update](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class) which triggers the `after_update` again ending in an endless loop.

Try giving [before_update](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/before_update) instead of `after_update`

```
before_update :check_phone

check_phone
  phone_validation if phone_changed?
end

def phone_validation
  code = Array.new(8){rand(36).to_s(36)}.join
  self.phone_verification_code = code
  self.save
end
```

Comment: That doesn't work in my case because the callback triggers some other code that must not be executed before the update.

Comment: Totally worked in my case! And prevents hitting the db twice so double-win. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def phone_validation
  code = Array.new(8){rand(36).to_s(36)}.join
  self.update_column(phone_verification_code,code)
end
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: No, because your syntax is wrong. It should either be `update_columns(name => value)` or `update_column(name, value)`

Comment: I've updated. Anyway, the logic would be working, right?

Comment: Yes, update_column does skip the callback. Unfortunately, it also skips the validation which is a deal breaker in my case.

Comment: Yes, in that case, you can use the logic in the accepted answer.