# self.save in rails model with neo4j db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

I am using neo4j 5.2.3. I have an after_update callback in my model agenda.rb

```
after_update : check_points
after_update : update_issue_points
```

In a method `update_issue_points` in my model agenda, I am doing a `self.save` as shown below which triggers the after_update callbacks resulting in an endless loop. In `Activerecord` we have ways to skip callbacks while salling `save`. But I am unable to find how to do such with ORM-like neo4j wrapper, neo4j.rb.

```
def update_issue_points
   agendas = owner.agendas
   self.issue_points = issue_points + 10.0
   self.save
end
```

How can I skip callbacks using neo4j.rb? Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE** This question is different from suggested duplicates because here the ORM is not ActiveRecord it is the neo4j.rb.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4: after\_update callback leads to endless loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23146304/rails-4-after-update-callback-leads-to-endless-loop)

Comment: It's true that ActiveNode != ActiveRecord, though check out the first part of that selected answer to find a way to set a variable to avoid an infinite loop.  I honestly don't know if the various non-`save` methods will do a save without callbacks, though I think we should map to ActiveRecord closely in cases like these.  Also if you don't care about saving the whole model, you could do `.query_as(:obj).set(obj: {issue_points: issue_points + 10.0}).exec` to execute a Cypher query directly